Packages renamed with package "to" attribute not available at local installation
I want to build a wheel package from a poetry project with a src layout. In order to make a whl file that includes all my subpackages I configure the TOML package in this fancy way:
packages = [
    { from="src", include = "**/*", to="ml_gold_km"},]

This provides a whl file that includes all my code under /ml_gold_km/ folder as expected.
The problem is that I cannot run any code in my development poetry environment, because it cannot find the ml_gold_km package. So all my imports prefixes with from ml_gold_km. fails.
I run poetry install, but it seems to install the package as src.
